# Changing data type and alternatives for Simulink's block SpaceState to improve Simulation performance

Tags: performance, matlab, state, space, simulink

I am new to Simulink and I have a basic question, which I could't find on the web.

I am using the **continuous Space-State** block from the Simulink library for developing a Model Block which only consists in that block, input&outputs and a constant block. I plan to use it as a **referenced block** in a bigger model, with roughly **200** of this referenced model blocks.

I **don't need double** precision, in fact I only need a few decimals and I wanted to **set** the signals data type of the model **to single**, for improvement on the performance of the simulation. Nevertheless the block doesn't let me to input single signals or to specify single coeficients for the A,B,C and D matrix parameters. For the first one it shows me this error:

> Only 'double' signals are accepted by block type StateSpace. The signals at the ports of 'ModeloGenerador/Subsystem/Generador' are of data type 'single'.

I would really appreciate any advise for this. I don't know if I am right by trying to reduce the data type size for improve the performance (maby its not a final factor in Simulink), or if I should be using another approach for getting a fast simulation for a model with 200 hundred Model blocks.

Thank you very much.